# Image scraping from google using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape first 3 images for a list of search strings from google. As i am not very well versed with Python, I have taken help from few sources & could write the below code. I need the images to be saved in respective folders(bearing the name of search string) in current Working directory. The code does create folder, but only for the first search string & that too an empty folder.

It is exiting with below error :-

```
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

The code is :-

```
def fetch_image_urls(query:str, max_links_to_fetch:int, wd:webdriver, sleep_between_interactions:int=3):
    search_url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjdh7KtreXqAhX8zIsBHbGHDGkQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq={query}&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CntRBYp7UQYNe7EGgAcAB4AIABywGIAcsBkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=MYwaX52rF_yZr7wPsY-yyAY&bih=578&biw=1280"
    wd.get(search_url)
    time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
    image_urls = set()
    image_count = 0
    number_results = 0
    for i in range(1,20):
        time.sleep(5)
        thumb = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.Q4LuWd")
        time.sleep(5)
        for img in thumb:
            print(img)
            print(img.get_attribute('src'))
            image_urls.add(img.get_attribute('src'))
            image_count = len(image_urls)
            number_results = image_count
            time.sleep(.5)
        print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links...")
return image_urls

def persist_image(folder_path:str,url:str):
    try:
        headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/84.0.4147.89'}
        image_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not download {url} - {e}")
    try:
        image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
        image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + '.jpg')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
        print(f"SUCCESS - saved {url} - as {file_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"ERROR - Could not save {url} - {e}")

def search_and_download(search_term:str,driver_path:str,target_path='./images',number_images=5):
    target_folder = os.path.join(target_path,'_'.join(search_term.lower().split(' ')))
    if not os.path.exists(target_folder):
        os.makedirs(target_folder)
    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path) as wd:
        res = fetch_image_urls(search_term, number_images, wd=wd, sleep_between_interactions=3)
        for elem in res:
            persist_image(target_folder,elem)

import requests
import os
import io
from PIL import Image
import hashlib

search_terms = ['1415 Bush St', '2015 Washington Blvd', '1420 Joh Ave', '901 W Ostend St']

for search_term in search_terms: 
    search_and_download(search_term=search_term, driver_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

Please suggest the correction/edits to produce desired output,

Thanks !!

Comment: try import time?

Comment: Importing time is not throwing an error, but the output is still the same. empty folder for just first search string. How can i generate the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with a workaround. Below code works exactly as per the requirement. Posting it for future help to anyone having similar requirement.

Thanks all for any help !!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import os
import urllib.request

searchterm = ['3500 Boston St','1415 Bush St','1811 POrtal St']
for i in searchterm:
    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+i+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXXX\xxxx\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)
    header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}

    counter = 0
    succounter = 0
    if not os.path.exists(i):
        os.mkdir(i)

    
    for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class,"rg_i Q4LuWd")]'):
        counter = counter + 1
        print("Total Count:", counter)
        print("Succsessful Count:", succounter)
        print("URL:", x.get_attribute('src'))

        img = x.get_attribute('src')
        new_filename = i+" " +str(counter)+".jpg"

        try:
            path = os.path.join(i , i + "_" + str(counter))
            path += new_filename
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, path)
            succounter += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

print(succounter, "pictures succesfully downloaded")
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
```

You need to import time for it to work.

Comment: Importing time is not throwing an error, but the output is still the same. empty folder for just first search string. How can i generate the desired output